# How can I use Traversal of Tinkerpop v3 instead of Frames of v2?

Tags: tinkerpop-frames, tinkerpop3

How can I write the following code unsing Tinkerpop v3?

```
 public interface Cat {
    @Relation(label="enemy")
    public void addEnemy(Mouse mouse);

    @Relation(label="enemy")
    public Collection getEnemies();
 }

 FramesManager manager = new FramesManager(graph);
 Cat tom = manager.frame(graph.getVertex(1), Cat.class);
 Mouse jerry = manager.frame(graph.getVertex(2), Mouse.class);
 tom.addEnemy(jerry);
```

I tried to find some example but I had no luck.

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: Which (maven?) dependencies are you using? Is Tinkerpop v3 still in beta?

Comment: I was using 3.0.0M6 but I abandoned the usage of the Tinkerpop

Comment: Cool, just curious, what're you using instead? (and why?)

Comment: Sorry about my late response @nick. Actually we stoped the project for while and I don't know if we'll continue with Graph Database. We tried Neo4J Community with Spring too, but there are some issues on API. Because of that we're thinking about the usage of NoSQL instead of Graph DB